# Java Jackson receive key with null value

Tags: java, json

I am dealing with some strange requirement, customer will send us the json below:

```
{ "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":null }
```

or

```
{ "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
```

I use Jackson library to parse the json, how can I identify the 2 json?
if my class is:

```
class Bean {
  private String key1;
  private String key2;
  private Integer key3;
  //setter, getter
}
```

both request will populate key1 as value1, key2 as value2, key3 as null

Comment: yes, this a duplicate question, thanks for your link